# fish runs some functions in .config/fish/config.fish while sourcing

Tags: fish

I'm trying the fish shell, and it seems to run *some* functions I've defined in it's config file when I open a new fish tab. For example, if I have this function:

```
function foo
cd ~/
end
```

fish will go into an infinite loop as it constantly `cd`'s into my user directory and sources the file. But if I have this:

```
function foo
ls
end
```

fish won't show me the output of `ls`. What is going on?

Comment: I saved your foo function and both of them work for me. maybe your promblem is with `ls` fuction.

Answer (score 1):

you may have defined `foo` as a function and it creates a infinte loop in someway.
try this

```
function foo
    command ls
end
```